# Graphql Mutation error - errors: [{message: "Variable "$firstName" of required type "String!" was not provided.",…}]

Tags: reactjs, axios, graphql

I'm trying to mutate a query in Graphql but for some reason, I can't grasp the syntax, I've tried multiple ways but maybe I'm having aye fatigue by this stage, would love if someone could point me in the right direction.

Here's my FormData:

```
const formData = {
        firstName: 'Jonny',
        lastName: 'Doe',
        IGHandle: {
            account: "xxx",
            number: 1

        },
    };
```

Here's my query:

```
const REGISTER = gql`
mutation RegisterMutation($firstName: String!, $lastName: String!, $account: String!, $number: Number!) {
    register(input: { firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName, account: $account, number: $number }) {
        firstName,
        lastName,
        IGHandle: {
            account:
            number:
        }
    }
}
```

`;

Here's my axios request:

```
axios({
        url: 'URL_HERE',
        method: 'post',
        data: { query: print(REGISTER) },
        variables: { ...formData },
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    }).then((result) => {
        console.log(result.data);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the input as below

```
mutation RegisterMutation($firstName: String!, $lastName: String!, $account: String!, $number: Number!) {
    register(firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName, account: $account, number: $number) {
```